# SQL :How To Convert text column like 22 Days 13 Hours 3 Minutes Into numeric Seconds?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This column is the delay in each process. Some examples of its value are

```
12 Seconds 
22 Days 12 Minutes 
14 Minutes 
1 Hour 10 mins
```

Days Hours Minutes Seconds are the only Units ?
Is it possible to convert it in sql?

Comment: It is possible, but do you really want to?  This type of problem (parsing) is much easier to solve using a language suited to parsing.... lisp, C, C++, C#, python, etc etc.  SQL is designed for working with relation sets of data (eg, how many rows have "minutes" in this field.

Comment: Don't have much options , since value is to read from db and stored in db

Comment: Your last example uses `mins` instead of `Minutes`. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select extract(epoch from interval '1 Hour 10 mins');
 date_part 
-----------
      4200
```

[`extract`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)